# Good idea to login with twitter?

Tags: php, mysql, twitter

I'm a student working on a small website/project for practice using PHP and learning to use API's. It's essentially a digg or reddit-like website, where users submit an article and others can upvote and comment on it. So far, I've had no way of restricting users to a single vote per submission.

I thought it might be a good idea to implement "log in with twitter", and associating whether a user has voted on something before with their twitter ID (or ID number). If the ID isn't recognized (they haven't logged onto my website with twitter before), their username would be added to a SQL database and their username would also be recorded in a seperate database for each question that they agree to.

My question is: Is this a good idea? Are there any reasons that this wouldn't work in the long term? I haven't had much experience with web development, so I don't know if I'm making some sort of security mistake or being incredibly inefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a better method, use OpenID like this website. I don't think it will be too hard.

Comment: I'll give that a shot then! There are no security risks?

Comment: I am afraid I don't know much about actual OpenID implementation. But as a user I like it. I don't need to create and remember passwords word the site support it. Probably you need to consult documentation. All I know is the target website will not get your password.

Answer (score 0):

Not everybody has a twitter account, and you can't obligate to create one for login in a specific website.